# issue: subview becoms on top of superview when it moves out of the superview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, subview

Here are two component, UIView *superView, and UILabel *label. label is a subview of superView. The issue is that the label will be on top of the superView, when I move the label out of its super view. Did not the label be invisible if it is out of its super view's frame?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIView` has a property `clipsToBounds`. Setting it to `YES` for your `superView` will make all views outside of its bounds be clipped.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you have linked your label with your IB and used IBOutlet while declaring your UILabel.
i.e
in .h file

```
     IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
```

link myLabel with the Label you created in IB.
if you have done that

just use [myLabel removeFromSuperview];

it will work.